# Can C# window service automatically log into custom eventsource/log

Tags: c#, windows-services, event-log, system.diagnostics

I have a C# window service where I am creating custom event source and log name in `ProjectInstaller.Designer.cs` file,

```
private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.serviceProcessInstaller1 = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller();
        this.serviceInstaller1 = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller();
        // 
        // serviceProcessInstaller1
        // 
        this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
        this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Password = null;
        this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Username = null;
        // 
        // serviceInstaller1
        // 
        this.serviceInstaller1.ServiceName = "DemoService";
        this.serviceInstaller1.StartType = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceStartMode.Automatic;

        var eventLog1 = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog();
        if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("MySource"))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(
                "MySource", "MyNewLog");
        }
        eventLog1.Source = "MySource";
        eventLog1.Log = "MyNewLog";

        // 
        // ProjectInstaller
        // 
        this.Installers.AddRange(new System.Configuration.Install.Installer[] {
        this.serviceProcessInstaller1,
        this.serviceInstaller1});

    }
```

and When I'm installing the window service the log name appears under `Applications and Service Logs`,

[image]

Now, will it possible that all unhanded exception from the service will log under `MyNewLog` with source 'MySource`?

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Currently it's logs under `Application` with source as 'Service1`

Comment: Are you catching unhandled exceptions and logging with your log class?

Comment: How without exception handling it's writes under `Application`, same way can I write under `MyNewLog`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Config EventLog in class constructor:

```
void InitiateEventLog(EventLog eventLog)
{
    if (!EventLog.SourceExists("MySource"))
    {
       EventLog.CreateEventSource("MySource", "MyNewLog");
    }
    eventLog.Source = "MySource";
    eventLog.Log = "MyNewLog";
}
```

Your constructor should be like:

```
public Service1()
{
    InitiateEventLog(EventLog);
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Then, you can catch unhandled exceptions in `OnStart` method and then write **CUSTOM** Log:

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
    }

    private void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        EventLog.WriteEntry($"Unhundeled Exception occurred: {(e.ExceptionObject as Exception).Message}");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but how eventLog1 reference will come here?  The name 'eventLog1' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @user584018 Service already contains EventLog property. Take a look at that property. I updated post

Comment: thanks, but still this is not writing anything under `MyNewLog`. Writing an event `service stated` under `Application`

Comment: @user584018 I added some changes I hope, it will work

Comment: Thanks, but it's not creates any custom log tag under `Applications and Service`, exception events still goes to `Application`

Comment: @user584018 I tested in my machine, it is logging under Applications and Services Logs. Did you add InitiateEventLog(EventLog); to your constructor?

Comment: Yes, `public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
 {
  public Service1()
  {
   InitiateEventLog(EventLog);
   InitializeComponent();
  }

  void InitiateEventLog(EventLog eventLog)
  {
   if (!EventLog.SourceExists("MySource1"))
   {
    EventLog.CreateEventSource("MySource1", "MyNewLog1");
   }

   eventLog.Source = "MySource1";
   eventLog.Log = "MyNewLog1";
  }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203225/discussion-between-dilshod-k-and-user584018).

Comment: Thanks, it's working. but we need to add `CreateEventSource` code in both service constructor as well as in `ProjectInstaller`?